# Which component-related website has this transformer? EPC-13 1.5mH; MFR: YUJING and AXIS

Tags: transformer, diagram

[image]

I have not had luck searching for it, which is a problem because i need to find it in either digital or physical stores and buy it (along with everything else in the diagram) for my project.

Comment: "Shopping" is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have to build it yourself from [these](https://www.power.com/sites/default/files/rtss/EPC-13_10pin_TDK_BEPC-13-1110CPH.pdf): -

[image]

Then you have to figure out how many turns to put on the primary and secondary windings. The 1.5 mH is likely the primary winding between pins 3 and 4 and that should be straightforward when estimating the turns but, the secondary is pure guesswork and ditto the auxiliary winding (pins 8 and 9).